# Using Wicket in conjunction with Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, jakarta-ee, wicket

I have a Java-application using Wicket for the frontend. Now I want gradually switch over to WordPress-frontend. First off, the startpage is going to be in WordPress. Is there a good way to use Wicket in conunction with WordPress? Wicket is so tightly coupled with the Java, I was unsure of how to do it.

If anyone can give me some best practices or tips, or links to people who have gone through similar scenarios i'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, what you are looking to do is likely impossible in the same runtime container.  There are ways to run PHP in Java ([Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) comes to mind), but some applications are not well suited for this.

If you want to run in multiple containers, you may be able to fake this out at the browser level with iframes, but you will need Wordpress plugins that can orchestrate setting iframe destinations to your current Tomcat container running Wicket.

It would be helpful to understand why you are doing this.  Wordpress has an excellent product, and this isn't to discourage you from going that direction.  But if you are just trying to gain CMS functionality, you may want to check out [Brix](http://www.brixcms.org), which is a Java Content Repository backend for Wicket.